# First and Last Number in String?

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I'm really struggling to extract two numbers from a string using Regex. The numbers can be positive, negative or 0. I have extremely limited experience of Regex.

The string always takes a format similar to:

```
"rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(-90deg)"
```

My best attempts are the following. This first approach gets me the first integer but does not get me the + / - sign:

```
var rx = string.replace( /(^.+\D)(\d+)(\D.+$)/i,'$2')
```

And, the following seems to get me the second, potentially as an element in an array but also does not get me the +/- sign:

```
var ry = string.match(/(\d+)/i);
```

Comment: And why do you need it? If you're having trouble with CSS matrices, you should say so, there are ways to parse those back etc.

Comment: If that is the answer then the question should be look for numbers following the plus and minus sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just look for [+ or - sign] followed by [one or more numbers] like this:

```
"rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(-90deg)".match(/([+-]?\d+)/g); // ["-90", "-90"]
```

It just returns an array of all matches, which you can check length of with `.length` to make sure it's got 2 things in it, then access them with `[0]` and `[1]`.

Comment: Thanks - this is probably me missing something obvious, but that seems to always return a two-match array, with both matches being the first of the two numbers - never the second.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on your approach - matching characters - I've come up with a really convoluted way of extracting the information I need. It works at least!

`code`
var rx2 = tempstring.match(/X\(-?\d+/);
    rx = rx[0].substring(2);
    var ry2 = tempstring.match(/Y\(-?\d+/) ;
    var ry = ry[0].substring(2);

Comment: Sorry - I missed a really important flag. Just add `g` after the / that ends the regex. It means "global" so the regex matches all occurrences, otherwise it breaks like you described :P